# How Do I Match All URL Variations (Relative Path)?

Tags: javascript, html, detection, detect

I need to modify a simple referrer URL JavaScript code to render content. Currently the script can only check a specific absolute URL, below is a sample of the code...

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf('http://www.domain.com/category1')==0){
document.writeln("From: Category One");
```

**How Do I...**

Modify script - referrer checks URL variations (possibility of "any" anchor and query string)

I am looking for this logic:
***IF REFERRER*** = domain.com/category1 + [# + anything] or [? + anything] ***THEN WRITE*** From: Category One

So that the script would render "Source: Category One" for any URL variations of the target page...

domain.com/category1
domain.com/category1#anything-here
domain.com/category1?anything-here

Comment: to get a full url: var a=document.createElement("a"); a.href=href; alert(a.href); // shows full url

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to modify your IF condition to be something like this

```
if (str.indexOf('http://www.domain.com/category1') !=-1)
```

Here is a plunk that I tried and worked on.

http://plnkr.co/edit/PQu1uIB7OUqNSO25xLbk?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, but I need a complete/cut & paste solution (as I am not a coder). Also, I need it to check against referring page...and if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of Hammad Khan, I merely needed to change...

**)==0){**
to 
**)>=0){**

You can use this code (modify as you see necessary)...

```
<script>
if (document.referrer.indexOf('http://www.domain.com/category1')>=0){
document.writeln("Source: Category One");
}
else if (document.referrer.indexOf('http://www.domain.com/category2')>=0){
document.writeln("Source: Category Two");
}
else {
document.writeln("Source: Category Other");
}
</script>
```